# ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (2187, 2069): given (1, 60860)

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, valueerror

I am trying to subtract numpy.array and dataframe and I get below error.

below is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-055925803390> in <module>()
----> 1 rmse = (sum(sum((test_- y)**2))/total_non_nan)**0.5
      2 print(rmse)
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (2187, 2069): given (1, 60860)
```

Looks like I have pandas 0.23.0 version. How can I upgrade Pandas version in my current anaconda version?